# Loan calculator using while loop

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a loan calculator and my loop keeps breaking. I got my stats correct, however I now need to move to a ListBox with more stats.

I can't get this while loop to work I have tried different ways with no avail. This is giving me a headache and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim principleamount As Decimal
    Dim numberofyears As Decimal
    Dim interestrate As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim paymentnumber As Decimal
    Dim currentbalance As Decimal
    Dim interestfortheperiod As Decimal
    Dim paymentamouhnt As Decimal
    Dim newbalance As Decimal
    Dim numberofpayments As Decimal
    Dim payment As Decimal
    Dim interestamount As Decimal
    Dim numberofperiods As Integer

    Private Sub btncalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalc.Click

        principleamount = txtprinciple.Text
        numberofyears = txtyears.Text

        'interest rate 
        If rba.Checked Then
            interestrate = 1.035
        End If
        If rbb.Checked Then
            interestrate = 1.04
        End If
        If rbc.Checked Then
            interestrate = 1.65
        End If
        If rbc.Checked Then
            interestrate = 1.08
        End If
        If rbd.Checked Then
            interestrate = 1.08
        End If
        If rbe.Checked Then
            interestrate = 0.1
        End If

        'monthly,weekly paymentplan
        If rbmonthly.Checked Then
            numberofpayments = numberofyears * 12
            interestfortheperiod = interestrate / 12
        End If
        If rbweekly.Checked Then
            numberofpayments = numberofyears * 26
            interestfortheperiod = interestrate / 26
        End If

        payment = (principleamount * interestfortheperiod) / (1 - (1 + interestfortheperiod) ^ -numberofpayments)

        txtpayment.Text = Format(payment, "#.00")

        While principleamount >= 0
            paymentnumber += 1
            lbpaydetails.Items.Add("Payment Number: " & paymentnumber & " Current Balance: " &  & "Interest for the Period: " &  & "Payment Amount:" &  & "new Balance:" & )
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is much wrong here. One thing for sure is you will never exit your while loop because you never change the condition to do so. Also please be more specific on what issue you are having so we can better help you.

Comment: I just cleaned up your question because it was unreadable the way it was posted. Please make sure your code is formatted correctly.  As Zaggler stated there is a lot wrong in your code, the main thing being is that there is nothing in your loop which alters the principleamount which will prevent it from **ever** exiting.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is going forever, so you need to find a way to decrease 'princlipleamount' **in** the loop. I am not entirely sure what the code does and how it behaves with your form, so i can not actually solve it.

P.S.
If you are trying to get 'numberofpayments' to be negative, don't put a dash in front of it like this:

```
payment = (principleamount * interestfortheperiod) / (1 - (1 + interestfortheperiod) ^ -numberofpayments))
```

But put it in Math.Abs() like this:

```
payment = (principleamount * interestfortheperiod) / (1 - (1 + interestfortheperiod) ^ Math.Abs(numberofpayments))
```

Also, you got a bracket missing at the end, i filled it in for you.

Good luck! ;)